# Extraction of Math -expressions with OCR from scanned photos?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Extraction of mathematical expressions with OCR would enormously help communication like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113711/explain-the-error-term-in-euler-method).

> 1. Is it possible do?
> 2. Is there some way easily to write into LaTex without keyboard?
> 3. Is there some way to make mathematical writing into Math SE easier?

Comment: Related: [Mathpix Snip Tool: Automatic LATEXLATEX\rm\LaTeX code generation from typed or handwritten math!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31106)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a related discussion on TeX.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr

[This particular tool](http://webdemo.visionobjects.com/equation.html?locale=default) called Web Equation does a rather remarkable job for a lot of mathematics expressions. Unfortunately it looks like it may be more intended for interaction with Tablets instead of scanned documents.

Comment: ...wow that is interesting, thanks for sharing the info +1. I did not realize there are more people on this problem, cool.

Comment: The link in the posts seems to be dead. I found something similar - but I am not sure whether it is a new location of the same project (or its continuation) or simply entirely different site to gets formulas from handwritten input: https://webdemo.myscript.com/

Comment: @MartinSleziak: it is the same company under a different name, at least according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43856/119) which asserts that Vision Objects became MyScript.

Answer (score 4):

In general, recognizing handwriting and turning it into text is very hard for computers, and depending on the handwriting nigh impossible. Throwing math symbols into the mix makes this almost certainly unfeasible at this point for *any* computer, much less for the servers that run math.SE to casually do every time they come across a picture. I'm afraid this really is a pony request (for those who don't know: a request that isn't going to happen, so you might as well ask for a pony too).

Answer (score 1):

By this thread suggested [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3735/5902), I was able to found the below details. I have so far investigated the hot European names but the thread also mentions some Japanese research so probably taking some time to really understand the status of this research. The key terms are **OCR, cluster-analysis, feature-extraction, feature-selection, image-processing, pre-processingg, decision-making** -- Wikipedia article outlining things [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) and SE threads below.

**Rigorous and mostly mathematical**

> - Adademic papers outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74895/2956)

**Practical problems, mostly education -related**

> - OCR for linewise-mathematical-formulae-working -thread [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr), hinted by this answer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3735/5902).
> - [Tablet for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand) and my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/204393/5902) covering some OCR -apps

**Programming biased**

> - OCR related info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=OCR), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dsp) -- relating to things such as OCR engines eg. Tesseract